# How to prove the follwing inequality $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \ge 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $$a+b+c=3abc$$
>   and $$a,b,c > 0$$
>   prove that $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq 8$$

I can fairly easily prove that 
$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq8abc$,
but then I get stuck.....since then I cannot move forward

If I was to prove that $abc\geq1$ this would have been easy but I am stuck, please help me.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

edit:I am incredibly sorry that I remembered the question incorrectly

Comment: $a=b=c=1{{{}}}$?

Comment: Any conditions on $a,b,c$, like being positive?

Comment: $ab+bc+ca \geq 3 (abc)^{\frac 2 3}.$

Comment: @lngix thanks for reminding me!!

Comment: Might not be provable because it's false. $a = b = c =1$ satisfies the antecedent and fails the consequent.

Comment: Is given that greater than or equal to zero looks like you want it proven.

Comment: @miniparser Sorry I am dumb!!!

Comment: Something is still wrong about the question. Take, for instance, $a=b=c=-1.$ If $a,b,c \geq 0$ is moved to the "if" part of the question then consider $a=b=c=0.$

Comment: I am guessing that the "if" part has also the condition that at least one of $a, b, c$ is non-zero.

Comment: Marwan Mizuri thanks,the problem is my friend told me this question so I am really struggling with the details,but I guess now I got 'em right

Comment: @Avi I see! One more note if you do not mind: If we have $a, b, c > 0,$ then each of the $(x+y)$ terms are going to be $\ge 2,$ and so the conclusion easily follows without the use of the first condition.

Answer (score 5):

Since $${a+b+c\over 3}\geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$

we get $$abc\geq \sqrt[3]{abc} \implies a^3b^3c^3\geq abc \implies a^2b^2c^2 \geq 1$$

Since $${x+y\over 2}\geq \sqrt{xy} \implies x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$$

so we have $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq 2\sqrt{ab}\cdot 2\sqrt{bc}\cdot 2\sqrt{ca} = 8\sqrt{a^2b^2c^2}\geq 8$$

Comment: thanks man!! but I am dumb and I got the question wrong,it would be extremely helpful if you can go through it once again mate!

Comment: is now any better?

Comment: I guess second step is wrong...since if x*y=1 and x>k this doesn't implies y>k.which you did on second step

Comment: What? Do you know what are you asking?

Comment: Maybe you didn't saw that I changed the question(since I got it wrong the first time).I am sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Well it would be more convenient to put it as another question then edit it.

Comment: if this helps I tried a pair 1,3,(√5)-2.

Comment: Of course is wrong since you put totaly new problem. As I said, put it as another question!

Comment: Sorry I am new to this website,I thought of that but thought people might not like the spam.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$a+b+c=3abc\leq3\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3,$$ which gives $$a+b+c\geq3.$$
Thus, $$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\geq\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)\sqrt{3abc(a+b+c)}=\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)^2\geq8.$$

Comment: Thanks man,but since I am dumb I got the question wrong can you please go through it once again?